# File size limit exceeded - transferring a file using fopen - php to ftp

Tags: php, ftp, fopen, file-transfer

I have a php file that connects to a remote ftp server, and writes a file. Recently, I've been getting an error that says "File Size limit exceeded" everytime it tries to run the following command. This has worked in the past and it is just now starting to happen.

The file is just 2 lines of text, so there shouldn't be a file size issue. Can anybody help me debug what is going on?

```
$varrate =$result->GetLastRealTimeMetalQuotesResult->MetalQuote->Rate;
$varrate = round($varrate,2);

$res = array($varrate, $varclose);
    print_r($res);
    // it's rate then close
    echo "\n"; 
    echo "time to die is ";
    echo $stopitafteraminute-$est;
$fp=fopen("ftp://user:pass@website.com/public_html/rpc-server/textfile.txt", "w", 0, $stream_context);       
foreach($res as $key => $value)
    {
        fwrite($fp,$value."\n");
    }
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file is not to big? Also do you have any PHP files over 2gb's?

Comment: well, I'm printing out what is supposed to be written in the 4th line. print_r($res);   <-- right there, and its literally 2 lines of text, about 6 characters each line.   What do you mean any php files over 2gbs? Any php files that exist on the entire server that is greater than 2gbs ?possibly some error logs? but why would that affect this? I'm almost positive there are no php files over 2gb

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it localy first, if it works than set the permission of the destination folder to 777 (just for testing purposes)
If none of them work then the problem is the 'stream'.

instead of doing the writing in a loop, create the file and then write it.

```
$file = "";
foreach($res as $key => $value)
    {
        $file.=$value."\n";
    }
 fwrite($fp,$file);
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote the file locally, and the resulting file was this: "1557.73
1558.64001465" for a total of 22 bytes. All i did was change the fopen to $fp=fopen("/localfolder/testfile.html", "w", 0, $stream_context);

Comment: It must be the stream then? How does one go about troubleshooting/debugging the stream?

Comment: I can't seem to even access the ftp at all, i'm just trying to access a file via file get contents and I get an error that says failed to open stream. here is what I'm doing.  $checkxtfile = file_get_contents ("ftp://pass:pass@website.com/public_html/rpc-server/file.txt");